# B2C Support for Yahoo

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Currently, in ACS we use Yahoo as an identity provider.  We noticed that Azure B2C doesn't offer Yahoo as a built-in social provider like Azure ACS.  Is there a reason for this and will it be added in the near future?

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3001761)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom). This allows you to integrate with any OpenId Connect provider.  It will require a bit of customization, but should be possible since [Yahoo supports OpenID Connect](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/).

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) the steps to get going with custom policies.